# Disabled Drag and Drog if it is month view in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, view, fullcalendar

I'm using FULLCALENDAR library to allocate external tasks.
I need fix 2 different things:

1) I need "drag and drop" disabled in month view only.

2) In month view: I need a task/event that is drag and dropped in the calendar to not be placed as allDay. Instead it should be placed into the business hours of 9am - 5pm.

This is my attempt at point 2, using businessHours

```
businessHours: {
    start: '9:00',
    end: '17:00',
    dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gonzalesc/7ycL8wed/

UPDATED:

I sorry, it seems to me badly explained at the point 1.
I need that the "**external events**" cannot drag into the calendar only in the monthly view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout view specific options in the [FullCalendar Docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View-Specific-Options/)

A simple example:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: { center: 'month,agendaWeek' }, // buttons for switching between views

    views: {
        month: { 
            editable: false
        }
    }
});
```

Regarding your second requirement, if you don't want all-day events at all, you can remove the slot and the all-day default for all views with:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    allDaySlot: false
    ...
 });
```

Edit:

Also, to only show 9:00 - 5:00 time slots in all views:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    minTime: "09:00:00",
    maxTime: "17:00:00",
    ...
});
```

Edit:

You can specify start times of external events when you initialize them. This will determine what time in the day they are placed in the calendar in a non-agenda view:

```
$(this).data('event', {
    title: $.trim($(this).text()), 
    stick: true, 
    start:'09:00'
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d49rvw5v/)

Comment: Hi. I try you solution, use "views" but  it doesn't work.  https://jsfiddle.net/gonzalesc/7ycL8wed/2/

Comment: You're right. Views option works, but allDayDefault option does not seem to function as i expected. I updated my answer and included a fiddle. Hope it helps.

Comment: I sorry, it seems to me badly explained.
with "editable:false" only prevents the event moves into the calendar

I need that the external events cannot drag into the calendar only in the monthly view.

Comment: Ok the point 1 I can solve it adding "droppable: false". Thanks @scottysmalls

Answer (score 0):

Ok the point 1 is solved. Thanks @scottysmalls

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: { center: 'month,agendaWeek' },

views: {
    month: { 
        editable: false,
        droppable: false
    }
}});
```

I think we're about to fix this point 2, but I don't know as put the condition that the it be a monthly view.

```
$(this).data('event', {
title: $.trim($(this).text()), 
stick: true, 
start:'09:00',
end: '17:00'
});
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused now - if drag and drop from external events in month view is not possible now because of both editable and droppable being false, why does it matter at what time they will be placed on a drop in month view? The user can't add any events to month view with these settings.